# Alert function is not working in the js code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

here is my Index file:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>The Database Entry Project</title></head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form>
            <h3>Input Details Here</h3>
            <label for="fn">First Name</label>
            <input id="fn" type="text">
            <label for="ln">Last Name</label>
            <input id="ln" type="text">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Register" id="sub">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" id="log">
            <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sub.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is sub.js

```
//-------------------------------Register----------------------------
$(function () {
    $('#sub').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var fn = $('#fn').val();
        var ln = $('#ln').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/login.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'fn': fn,
                'ln': ln
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            cache: false
        }); // end ajax call
    });
});
//-------------------------Login---------------------------------------
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#log').on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var fn = $('#fn').val();
   var ln = $('#ln').val();

   $.ajax({
      url: 'php/log.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: { 'fn': fn , 'ln': ln },
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);

      },
      cache: false
    }); // end ajax call

   });
});
```

this is sub.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'config.php';
$fn = $_POST['fn'];
$ln = $_POST['ln'];
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tab1(fn,ln)VALUES(?,?)");
$stmt->execute(array($fn, $ln));
echo "Saved Successfully";
?>
```

this is log.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'config.php';

$fn = $_POST['fn'];
$ln = $_POST['ln'];
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT fn, ln FROM tab1 WHERE fn=? AND ln=?");
// $stmt->bindValue(1, $fn);
// $stmt->bindValue(2, $ln);
$stmt->execute(array($fn,$ln));
$row = $stmt->fetch();

if($row > 0) {
  echo "Login Successful";
}

else {
  echo "Login failed.";
}

?>
```

The config file for connecting to database is working properly.

PHP files are working right(when individually tested)

I don't understand why alert function is not working in sub.js file and also why data is not inserting in the database.

Comment: You are imported jQuery liabrary?

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript error in your console?

Comment: Add an 'error` callback to you ajax, so you can see if there are any server side errors, and look in the js console for js errors

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Answer (score 4):

Your JavaScript error console will be complaining that `$` is undefined.

You are including `sub.js` (which depends on jQuery) **before** you include `jquery.js`.

Swap the order of your script elements.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your HTML & use jquery before its functions get called in sub.js:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>The Database Entry Project</title></head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form>
            <h3>Input Details Here</h3>
            <label for="fn">First Name</label>
            <input id="fn" type="text" /> 
            <label for="ln">Last Name</label>
            <input id="ln" type="text" /> 
            <br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Register" id="sub" />
            <input type="submit" value="Login" id="log" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
        </form>

    </div>
    <!-- JQUERY should be called before using it's functions-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sub.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why add the name attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Quentin's answer is right. I want you to advise, in addition, that for better handling now and in the future jQuery ajax calls, it is best that you use done() and fail() construct methods, as explained [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) :

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: 'myurl',
cache: false,
async: true,
data: {}, // object to pass
type: 'post',
dataType: 'json' // if necessary
}).done(function(d){
    // some stuffs here...alert(d)?
}).fail(function(j,s,e){
    // manage errors here
})
```

Hope this helps